# Itertools.accumulate to find union of intervals (convert from reduce to accumulate)

Tags: python, intervals, python-itertools, functools, accumulate

I seem to have developed the right `reduce` operation to find the union of intervals, only to realize that `reduce` gives you a final result. So I looked up the documentation and figured out that what I should be using is in fact `accumulate`.

I need someone to help me convert this `reduce` to `accumulate` so I have the intermediate intervals

The code below is an example of how I used `reduce`. I'm assuming that the intermediate values can be stored using `accumulate`. I'm not sure if this is even possible.. But I looked at examples how `accumulate` gives you a list of items where each item is an intermediate calculated result.

```
example_interval = [[1,3],[2,6],[6,10],[15,18]]

def main():

    def function(item1, item2):


        if item1[1] >= item2[0]:

            return item1[0], max(item1[1], item2[1])

        else:

            return item2

    return reduce(function, example_interval)
```

To understand the problem, `[1, 3], [2, 6]` can be reduced to `[1, 6]` since `item1[1] >= item2[0]`, `[1, 6]` is then taken in as `item1` and then compared to `[6,10]` which is `item2`, to give `[1, 10]`. `[1, 10]` is then compared with the final item `[15, 18]`, in this case, it is not merged, so the final result is `[1, 10], [15, 18]`.

I do know how to do this problem without `reduce` and `accumulate`. **I just have a general interest in understanding how I can use `accumulate` to replicate this task where intermediate values are stored.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from itertools import accumulate

def function(item1, item2):
    if item1[1] >= item2[0]:
        return item1[0], max(item1[1], item2[1])
    return item2

example_interval = [(1,3),(2,6),(6,10),(15,18)]
print(list(accumulate(example_interval, function)))
```

Result is:

```sh
[(1, 3), (1, 6), (1, 10), (15, 18)]
```

Notice that i changed the items on `example_interval` from lists to tuples.
If you dont do that, when `item1[1] < item2[0]`, the returned value is `item2`
which is a list object, but if `item[1] >= item2[0]`, the returned expression is `item1[0], max(item1[1], item2[1])`, which is transformed to a tuple:

```py
example_interval = [[1,3],[2,6],[6,10],[15,18]]
print(list(accumulate(example_interval, function)))
```

Now the output is:

```sh
[[1, 3], (1, 6), (1, 10), [15, 18]]
```